# SSRS Filters Multiple values

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have parameter called CodeValue (**it is not a multivalued parameter it is just a string**) which is optional or passed as comma delimited string (multipevalue) from application to SSRS Report.

I have configured SSRS filter expression like

```
=ISNOTHING(Parameters!CodeValue.Value) or (Fields!Code.Value = Parameters!CodeValueValue) and Type as "Boolean" operator as "=" and Value as "True"
```

When I pass multiple value in frontend for Parameter Codevalue it is not returning any records. How will I do something line seen below

```
=ISNOTHING(Parameters!ICD_1.Value) or (Fields!ICD_1.Value In Parameters!ICD_1.Value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by means of below expression

```
=Iif(IsNothing(Parameters!ICD_1.Value)=True,
True,Iif(InStr(Parameters!ICD_1.Value,IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!ICD_1.Value)=true,"*@*",Fields!ICD_1.Value))>0,true,false))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the JOIN function:

```
=ISNOTHING(Parameters!ICD_1.Value) or (CStr(JOIN(Parameters!ICD_1.Value,",")).Contains(Fields!ICD_1.Value ))
```

Comment: it resulted in error.. Parameters.ICD_1.value will be like "1,2,3" and Fileds ICD_1 can have value like 1 or 2 or 3 or null for each of records

Comment: tablix resulted in error.. I got it working by means of below expression... but it also shows value that has NULL in ICD_1 column.. can you pls help me =Iif(IsNothing(Parameters!ICD_1.Value)=True,True,Iif(InStr(Parameters!ICD_1.Value,Fields!ICD_1.Value))>0,true,false)

Comment: Just wrap your current expression with another IIF(IsNothing(Fields!ICD_1.Value), False, ...)

Comment: will it not be a performance hindrance... to replace with statement like this =Iif(IsNothing(Parameters!ICD_1.Value)=True,
True,Iif(InStr(Parameters!ICD_1.Value,IIF(ISNOTHING(Fields!ICD_1.Value)=true,"ab",Fields!ICD_1.Value))>0,true,false))